# How to merge 4 dataframes into one

Tags: pandas, merge

I have created a functions that returns a  dataframe.Now, i want merge all dataframe into one. First, i called all the function and used reduce and merge function.It did not work as expected.The error i am getting is "cannot combine function.It should be dataframe or series.I checked the type of my df,it is dataframe not functions. I don't know where the error is coming from.

```
def func1():
  return df1

def func2():
  return df2

def func3():
  return df3

def func4():
  return df4

def alldfs():
  df_1 = func1()
  df_2 = func2()
  df_3 = func3()
  df_4 = func4()

result = reduce(lambda df_1,d_2,df_3,df_4: pd.merge(df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4,on ="EMP_ID"),[df1,df2,df3,df4)
 print(result)
```

Comment: The things you are doing feel all sorts of wrong ... from a Python and Pandas perspective.  You should reevaluate what you are trying to do and ask how to do that.

Comment: sorry for all the messy code. All i wanted to do was merge all 4 dataframes into one. I will have more than 4 dataframes so, i was trying the convenient way to merge all

Comment: `pd.concat([d.set_index('EMP_ID') for d in [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]], axis=1)`

Comment: or if you insist on a reduction type answer (though slower) `reduce(lambda a, b: a.merge(b, on='EMP_ID'), [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4])`

Comment: Will it be extremely slow if i have to merge 10 dataframes. Dataframes are of small size though

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this ( assuming that `EMP_ID` is common across all dataframes and you want the intersection of all dataframes ) -

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='EMP_ID').merge(df3, on='EMP_ID').merge(df4, on='EMP_ID')
```